# Error visualising data using Bokeh hovertool tooltips function in Python

Tags: python, bokeh

1st post here and new to python so go easy on me!

I have plotted my visualisation in python using bokeh library. I've used the hovertool function but cant seem to display any data when I hover over it. Not sure where I am going wrong here. Any support welcome.

## Bokeh Libraries

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

from bokeh.io import output_file

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, NumeralTickFormatter

from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_notebook()
```

## Store the data in a ColumnDataSource

```
df = ColumnDataSource(contents)
```

## Specify the selection tools to be made available

```
select_tools = ['box_select', 'lasso_select', 'poly_select', 'tap', 'reset']
```

## Create the figure

```
fig = figure(plot_height=400,
         plot_width=600,
         x_axis_label=' Store Average Age of Respondent',
         y_axis_label=' Store NPS Percentage Score %',
         title='MNWIOM Average Customer Age Vs. NPS Percentage Score by Store',
         toolbar_location='below',
         tools=select_tools)
```

## Add square representing each store

```
fig.square(x='Average Age of Respondent',
       y='NPS Percentage Score',
       source=df,
       color='royalblue',
       selection_color='deepskyblue',
       nonselection_color='lightgray',
        nonselection_alpha=0.3)
```

## Format the tooltip

```
tooltips = [('Store','@Store Name'),
        ('Average Customer Age', '@Average Age of Respondent'),
        ('NPS Score %', '@NPS Percentage Score'),]
```

## Configure a renderer to be used upon hover

```
hover_glyph = fig.circle(x='Average Age of Respondent', y='NPS Percentage Score', source=df,
                     size=15, alpha=0,
                     hover_fill_color='black', hover_alpha=0.5)
```

## Add the HoverTool to the figure

```
fig.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, renderers=[hover_glyph]))
```

## Visualize

```
show(fig)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your fieldnames have spaces, you have to use curly brackets {} in your tooltips definition. From the hovertool docs ([link](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool)):

```
tooltips=[
    ( 'date',   '@date{%F}'            ),
    ( 'close',  '$@{adj close}{%0.2f}' ), # use @{ } for field names with spaces
    ( 'volume', '@volume{0.00 a}'      ),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! The missing curly brackets {} solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Hovertool inside the figure variable.

```
fig = figure(plot_height=400,
         plot_width=600,
         x_axis_label=' Store Average Age of Respondent',
         y_axis_label=' Store NPS Percentage Score %',
         title='MNWIOM Average Customer Age Vs. NPS Percentage Score by Store',
         toolbar_location='below',
         tools=[HoverTool(tooltips=[('Store','@Store Name'),('Average Customer Age', 
        '@Average Age of Respondent'),('NPS Score %', '@NPS Percentage Score')])])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your solution and it also works great!

Comment: I am glad it worked. Now I would ask you to click the positive tick next to the code in order to have a better reputation. Happy coding!